# Как в Firebase c помощью addDoc добавить уникальный ключ в документ на React.js

Tags: reactjs, firebase

Есть данные, которые должны добавляться в Firebase, и с этими данными хочу добавить уникальный ключ, который дает Firebase. Не понимаю в чем ошибка, так как не добавляется.

```
   const database = collection(db, 'posts')
   const {register, handleSubmit, formState: {errors}} = useForm()
    const add = async(post) => {
          await addDoc(database, {...post}).then((docRef) => 
             ({...post, uniqueID : docRef.id})
          )
       }

 return <>
       <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(add)}>
         <div>
            <input type="text" placeholder="title" {...register('title')}/>
         </div>
         <div>
            <input type="text" placeholder="description" {...register('description')}/>
         </div>
         <div style={{marginTop: '5px'}}>
            <button>Add Post</button>
         </div>
      </form>
   </>
```

uniqueiID - никак не отображается.

Comment: Так проверь что приходит в `.then((docRef) => ...)`

Comment: При консоле docRef.id нужный отображается

Comment: А как используется функция `add`?

Answer (score 0):

> Не понимаю в чем ошибка

Показанная функция ничего не возвращает. А вот такой вариант вернет нужные данные.

```
const add = async post => {
    const docRef = await addDoc(database, {...post})
    return {...post, uniqueID : docRef.id}
}
```

Comment: const {register, handleSubmit, formState: {errors}} = useForm()
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(add)}>
         <div>
            <input type="text" placeholder="title" {...register('title')}/>
         </div>
         <div>
            <input type="text" placeholder="description" {...register('description')}/>
         </div>
         <div>
            <button>Add Post</button>
         </div>
      </form>

Comment: При добавлении в форме надо получить id которое предоставляет Firebase, например вот такой 
3jQeZ1GGiA1RFMDOC хочу поместить в uniqueID внутри документа

Comment: @Андрей, ты можешь отредактировать свой ответ. Т.о. весь твой код будет лучше виден. Но сразу напомню что твоя функция `add` асинхронная и получать из нее данные придется асинхронно.

Comment: Отредактировал.

Comment: @Андрей, если `handleSubmit` не умеет работать с асинхронными функциями тебе не получится что-то передать из асинхронной функции `add`.